# Dropdown UIView inside UITableView Section Headers

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiview

I need to add a customised dropdown UIView into the UITable section header as part of the design requirements. I have successfully added the the dropdown UIView into the section header but when I try to click on the Title inside the dropdown, it wouldn't recognise that I have make a selection on my dropdown UIView, instead it will fire off didSelectRowAtIndexPath of the big UITableView underneath. It seems like I can't make a selection of items that are display outside the section header height if it's added to the section header.

[image: See the image]

I'm not using a UITableView for the popup UIView. Each row is a UIButton and attached with Touch Up Inside event listener. When I try to click on the buttons, it wouldn't detect I clicked on the buttons but it will take it that I've clicked on Cupertino. A tag is attached to each each button.

This is an example of how I handle the event.

```
-(IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];

    switch (sender.tag) 
    {
        case 0:        
         #Do something
        break;

        case 1:        
         #Do something
        break;
   }
}
```

When I try to expand the section header height, the buttons that fall inside the section header can be clicked. For e.g. Title 1 can be clicked but Title 2 and 3 cannot.

Comment: if you tried to select title 1 cell then not working?

Comment: Nope, it's not working. The row (Cupertino) will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

If your project does not restrict you to use a third party library, i would suggest using [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover). Its customisable and you can make it look like yours if you want to. Plus it has the method buttonClicked which you can use to solve your problem. Also it behaves much like the UIPopover but you can use it on the iPhone as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can use 3rd party library but just wanted to find out if there's any solution to this problem since I have already coded it. I will try out FPPopover.

Comment: The info you have provided in the question is not enough. Of course, it will use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method for your issue to be solved. Plus, the UIView you have created should be a UITableViewController and have its own class